# Soap web service not displaying nulls

Tags: java, soap, glassfish

I'm making a SOAP service. The structure looks like this:

```
>             <Person>
>                 <contactID>122</contactID>
>                 <firstName>Jimmy</firstName>
>                 <middleName>T.</middleName>
>                 <suffix>Jr.</suffix>
>                 <emailAddress>jim@m.net</emailAddress>
>                 <birthDate>1969-09-01T00:00:00-07:00</birthDate>     
>             </Person>
```

If the birthdate is null, my service will omit that node giving a response like the folowing:

```
>             <Person>
>                 <contactID>122</contactID>
>                 <firstName>Jimmy</firstName>
>                 <middleName>T.</middleName>
>                 <suffix>Jr.</suffix>
>                 <emailAddress>jim@m.net</emailAddress> 
>             </Person>
```

I need something that states that is null like:

```
>             <Person>
>                 <contactID>122</contactID>
>                 <firstName>Jimmy</firstName>
>                 <middleName>T.</middleName>
>                 <suffix>Jr.</suffix>
>                 <emailAddress>jim@m.net</emailAddress>
>                 <birthDate>null</birthDate>     
>             </Person>
```

I'm using java and glassfish. is it possible to accomplish this? by the way, birthDate is a Date.
Thank you

Comment: What do you use to generate the XML from your classes?

Comment: I'm using netBeans which generates the wsdl automatically

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain so I can fix it. It is not constructive to downvote without a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to annotate my variable in the Person class as follows:

```
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(nillable=true, required=true) //added this
    public Date birthDate;

}
```